# How to route outside of components in react-router 4?

Tags: react-router

In react router 3 the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md) include a way for navigating outside of components. React router 4 seems to have dropped support for this and the only way of navigating outside components is to [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) on a component and forward the history to wherever you need it.

Personally I find this to be impractical and leading to more entangled and verbose code. My question thus is: Am I missing an alternative way for how to navigate outside components?

Answer (score 7):

Just wrap the app in an extended BrowserRouter:

```
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default class YourBrowserRouter extends BrowserRouter {
   render() {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
           <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
           </Switch>
        </Router >
    )
 }
}
```

And `import { history }` ... `history.push('/login')` where you need it outside of react components. For me I wanted to redirect to the login page from within my fetch utility method if the server responded with a 401.

Comment: Seems react-router has no prop `history`

Answer (score -1):

If all you're wanting to do is navigate to a new page, [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) is the recommended way. If you've already seen that and for some reason it won't work, then no, you're not missing anything and withRouter is how you gain access to history from outside a route.